# maintain the existing variables android

Tags: android

I have an application in android which calls for 2 variables at the start of this, name and email, to write I click on the next button and it sends me to the next page.

I would like to know how to maintain the existing variables in the application internally, as when the user exits the application and log back will appear in the box name and email data already written and just need to click the button to continue .

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the data as a SharedPreference. The syntax goes like this:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
Editor edit = sp.edit();
edit.putString("EMAILADDRESS", valueOfEmailAddress);
edit.putString("NAME", valueOfNameVariable);
edit.commit(); //committing the changes to memory
```

Then when you start your activity next time use the following to get those values from memory:

```
SharedPreferences sp1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
String emailAdd = sp1.getString("EMAILADDRESS", "");
String name = sp1.getString("NAME", "");
```

Then set the `emailAdd` as the text for your email `EditText` and `name` as the text for your name `EditText`.